# Generate bit vector with t random ones

Tags: c++, matlab, vector, random, bit

I want to generate an array/vector `v` of size `p` with `t` ones and `p-t` zeros. The position of the `t` ones **must** be random.

This is the solution that I've written so far, but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient one. In addition I never used `random_device` or `mt19937` (found them [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)) before, so I don't know what are the possible drawbacks.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
...
int p=10, t=3;
std::vector<int> v(p,0);
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)  //better way?
    v[i] = 1;
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
std::shuffle(std::begin(v), std::end(v), g);
```

This is the matlab code that I'm trying to reproduce:

```
rp = randperm(p);
I_s(i,:) = rp(1:t);
v = zeros(p,1);
v(I_s(i,:)) = 1;
```

[Demo here!](http://ideone.com/Huceoh)

Comment: `std::fill` may replace your loop.

Comment: Btw, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place.

Comment: This don't look as "bit-vector". It is simple vector of integers!

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the tip, I think std::fill_n is even a better solution. And yes, maybe codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place, hoping some admin move it

Comment: @justHelloWorld You can mod flag this and ask for them to move it.

Comment: @Jarod42 I disagree this would be a valid question for SE Code Review, because obviously the code doesn't work as intended (required).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: As I understand OP want a random permutation of a vector with `t` `1`, and `p-t` `0`. so code seems to work.

Comment: Intent might be clearer with `std::vector<bool>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::shuffle(std::begin(v), std::end(v), g);
```

Doesn't make the bit position random, it just changes the positions of the existing items (which all have the zero position bit set) in the vector randomly.

---

If I understood your requirement correctly, What you actually should have is something like:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g(rd());
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
     v[i] = 1 << rd(); // set a random bit position
```

Comment: My logic is a little bit different: initialize v with 0, fill the first t positions with ones, randomly permutate v through std::shuffle. Trust me, it works ;)

Comment: @justHelloWorld I doubt _it works_. _"The position of the t ones must be random."_ There's no code in your sample to manipulate the bit positions.

Comment: @justHelloWorld So your `std::vector<int>` is meant to represent a single bit in each element? That looks extremely inefficient for me. You're probably better of with a `std::bitset`or even the infamous `std::vector<bool>` specialzaiton.

Comment: You're right, but this is going to be used in `Eigen`, where you cannot declare a `bool` or `std::bitset` vecotr, unfortunately.